# In Android moving the app's data whenever the app is moved from internal memory to sdcard vice versa

Tags: android, database, android-sdcard

Is there any way to move the *data along with the app whenever the user moves the app from sdcard to internal memory and vice versa. I don't want app to handle this and would like to implement in a way that the OS itself taking care of everything while moving the app.

*data (some large size ~50MB files would downloaded and stored in the data folder. Those files should be accessed by another application ( using content provider))

I planned the following but it does not seems effective solution.

1. If there is any broadcast intent which tells when the app is moved between sdcard and internal, The app can listen and move the files.
2. If there is no broadcast intent for option 1, During the launch check whether the app install location is sdcard or internal and move the files.

Is there any right way to implement this?

Comment: how about: 3. always install at external storage? If you use [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29), the files will be removed if the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Lie Ryan, Thanks for you r comment. Actually I want to move the data along with app whenever the user move the app between sdcard and internal memory. This is to make sure to give the user option to use the App without dependent on sdcard. Some point user may use the sdcard and want to move the entire app to sdcard and free the internal memory. So I want to carry all the data wherever the app goes.